# How can I use dependsOn on copy resources in nested deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a RG tag for saving the roleAssignments version. I want that the tag deployment will be depended on the creation of the roleassignments. the roleassignments are created by using "copy" and the deployment is nested (since I need to change the scope to another RG and subscription).

I'm getting the following error message: {"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[uniqueString(concat('nonRegionalRoleAssignments-', parameters('resourceId'), variables('roleAssignmentsToCreate')[copyIndex()].roleDefinitionId))]' at line '82' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'."}
How can I resolve it?

The template:

```
{
  "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdentityName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the managed identity resource."
      }
    },
    "roleAssignmentsDefinitionIds": {
      "type": "Array"
    },
    "roleAssignmentsVersion": {
      "defaultValue": 0,
      "type": "Int"
    },
    "resourceId": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "rolesAssignmentsResourceGroup": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "rolesAssignmentSubscriptionID": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "roleAssignmentsToCreate",
        "count": "[length(parameters('roleAssignmentsDefinitionIds'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[guid(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName')), resourceGroup().id, parameters('roleAssignmentsDefinitionIds')[copyIndex('roleAssignmentsToCreate')])]",
          "roleDefinitionId": "[parameters('roleAssignmentsDefinitionIds')[copyIndex('roleAssignmentsToCreate')]]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "roleAssignmentVersionTagName": "[concat(parameters('managedIdentityName'), 'RoleAssignmentVersion')]",
    "roleAssignmentsVersionTags": {
      "tags": {
        "[variables('roleAssignmentVersionTagName')]": "[parameters('roleAssignmentsVersion')]"
      }
    },
   "updatedResourceGroupTags": "[union(resourceGroup(), variables('roleAssignmentsVersionTags')).tags]",
    "roleAssignmentsDefaultVersion": {
      "tags": {
        "[variables('roleAssignmentVersionTagName')]": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
      "name": "[uniqueString(concat('nonRegionalRoleAssignments-', parameters('resourceId'), variables('roleAssignmentsToCreate')[copyIndex()].roleDefinitionId))]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {},
        "copy": {
                "name": "roleAssignment",
                "count": "[length(variables('roleAssignmentsToCreate'))]",
                "mode": "serial",
                "batchSize": 1
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "[guid(parameters('resourceId'), 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', variables('roleAssignmentsToCreate')[copyIndex()].roleDefinitionId, resourceGroup().id)]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
              "condition": "[less(int(union(variables('RoleAssignmentsDefaultVersion'), resourceGroup()).tags[variables('roleAssignmentVersionTagName')]), parameters('roleAssignmentsVersion'))]",
              "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
              "properties": {
                "principalId": "[reference(parameters('resourceId'), '2018-11-30').principalId]",
                "roleDefinitionId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',  variables('roleAssignmentsToCreate')[copyIndex()].roleDefinitionId)]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "subscriptionId": "[parameters('rolesAssignmentSubscriptionID')]",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rolesAssignmentsResourceGroup')]"
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```json
  "dependsOn": [
    "roleAssignment"
  ],
```

From the tags resource - it's not needed.

Comment: Why it's not needed?

Comment: dependsOn is used to sequence the resources in the deployment.  The tags resource does not need to wait for the roleAssignment because the tag will be applied with the credentials of the principal doing the deployment.

Comment: The dependsOn purpose here, is not for the credentials and the ability to deploy the tags, but to set the roleAssignments version under the tag, and I don't want to set the new version if the role assignments deployment failed.

Comment: A few thoughts... 1) what you're doing is a bit of an anti-pattern in ARM.  ARM is declarative so should always be goal seeking, not partially so 2) what's the expectation when the tag is set but the roleAssignment or the principal is removed (post deployment)?  3) what's the expectation when some of the roleAssignments succeed and others do not?  No tags would be set in that case (with the current template) but some assignments will still exist.